# Netty 4 using a different key other than Channel to maintain event order

Tags: netty

In Netty 3 there is an OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor and in documentation described how to change ordering key: http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/execution/OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor.html

In Netty 4 this was class replaced with EventExecutorGroup approach. As I understand if I will use DefaultEventExecutorGroup it will maintain order by channel (btw, is it correct?). But if I have several sessions multiplexed on one channel and i want to use other key for parallel execution then channel is there a way to make it in Netty 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with anything that is provided by Netty itself atm. You may be able to use a custom EventExecutorInvoker which will be part of Netty 4.1. Could you please open an issue with your use-case explained at our issue tracker so we can keep track ?

Comment: Thanks for answer. Here is added issue: https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/2498